# file not found, but the file is there

Tags: linux, android, emulator

running an Ubuntu 14.04 x64, I like to execute an binary file. This one:

```
$ ls -la /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tho tho 35640 Nov 19 14:46 /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
```

If I run the executable as user tho, the following `file not found` error occours:

```
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
bash: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator:  no such file or directory
```

I tried the following commands:

```
$ file /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

`readelf -l emulator` returned without any errors.

`ldd emulator` says, that this program is **not** dynamically linked

```
$ strace  /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator
execve("/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator", ["/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emu"...], [/* 64 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

What could be the reason for that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running 64-bit Linux, but the Android SDK tools are 32-bit. At the same time, you don't have the 32-bit compatibility libraries installed on your system.

So you just need to install those:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: `apt-get` returned the information, that `ia32-libs` is not available, but it's replaced by `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`  -> installing those packages will solve that problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad this got resolved but I'm curious why bash would say `emulator:  no such file or directory`? The file `emulator` exists, shouldn't it give an error about dependencies or have the executable itself throw an error?